# ANOVA degrees of freedom

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, fixed-effects-model

I'm running the following test

```
anova(fixed_model, random_model, test="LRT")
```

and I get the following results.

```
Data: review_data
Models:
fixed_model: y ~ (1 | x1)
random_model: y ~ (1 + x2 | x1)
             npar   AIC   BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
fixed_model     3 13591 13610 -6792.5    13585                       
random_model    5 13590 13622 -6790.1    13580 4.8949  2    0.08651 .
```

Why are the degrees of freedom 2 and not 1 if random_model only adds a random slope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The larger model adds both a variance of random slopes across groups and the covariance between the slope and the intercept.  If you look at `summary(random_model)` (or `VarCorr(random_model)`) you should see estimates for both parameters.

If you want the intercept and slope to be independent you can probably use `(1 + x2 || x1)` (although this depends on what package you're using, which you haven't shown us).

If this is your actual model and not a simplified example, you should consider including `x2` as a fixed effect as well, because random effects are zero-centered (i.e., your `random_model` assumes that the population average slope is exactly zero).